# cannot access trendnet wireless box

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

My **Trendnet TEW-452BRP** wireless router is connected with a **NetGear ProSafe VPN firewall FVS318** router right now. They are working fine. I am right now connected with wireless. I try to change the password of the wireless but cannot access the wireless box. The default ip, `**http://192.168.1.1**,`  doesn't work any more. If I type `http://192.168.0.1`. I will be connected to the NetGear firewall. How can I find the ip for my wireless box? I am using Win7. The ipconfig result is this:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : homegroup
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::196a:37a4:df0e:2851%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.5
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : homegroup

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ec07:a30a:81e6:f52e%21
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.homegroup:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : homegroup

Tunnel adapter isatap.{821727DD-0180-41C3-A219-80D10868C313}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Reusable ISATAP Interface {94370EFA-E390-4B02-8F64-CD51435CA84D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:1c11:29b8:3f57:fffa
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1c11:29b8:3f57:fffa%15
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BFECF395-FF0C-47A4-8AC3-026B93C26ACF}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{4C7BE1F9-D273-4981-9D62-B96EE86BC87C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on the 192.168.0.x/24 network and the wireless management page is at 192.168.1.1/24, then you are on two different networks. You'll need to temporarily assign yourself a static ip address on the 192.168.1.x network in order to access the wireless management page.